# How to trigger requests with a button using React-query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I have been trying to learn React-query but can't seem to trigger requests with my `onSubmit` event. Right now the code is sending the request with "washington" as the default parameter and printing it to the screen, and a new request also triggers with the `onBlur` event, and fetch the data if the city typed is valid.

The thing is that wish I could move this logic to the `submit()` function, treat the data on the input and only if the data is valid, proceed to make the request. This is the stackblitz where I reproduced the problem with a free apiKey: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cv52rp?file=src/view/weather.js)

This is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import axios from 'axios';

const Fetch = async city => {
  let apiKey = '91b5ff77e9e7d1985a6c80bbbb3b2034';
  const { data } = await axios.get(
    `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${apiKey}&units=metric`
  );
  return data;
};

const Weather = () => {
  const [city, setCity] = useState('washington');
  const { data, error } = useQuery(['temperature', city], () => Fetch(city));

  const submit = () => {};

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={submit}>
        <input onBlur={e => setCity(e.target.value)} type="text" />
        <button type="submit">send</button>
      </form>
      {!data ? null : <div>{data.main.temp}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Weather;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [useMutation hooks](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/mutations). As what the documentation said `mutations are typically used to create/update/delete data or perform server side-effects. For this purpose, React Query exports a useMutation hook.`. This hooks will return an object that gives you a mutation function that you can use to trigger request based on user interactions.

`const { mutate: renamedMutationFunction } = useMutation(newTodo => axios.post('/todos', newTodo))`.

Then somewhere in your code, you can do:

`const handleClick = () => { renamedMutationFunction(); //invoking the mutation }`

#### EDIT

see @TkDodo answer for better solution. You can basically just re-set the city, and react-query will automatically refetch the data.

Comment: useMutation is not the way to go here. useMutation is for mutations (create, update, delete) because they are imperative. Furthermore, they don't create entries in the cache, you can't re-use the data in multiple components. Basically, you have no state management, no refetches and none of the goodies of react-query if you useMutation for GET requests.

Comment: @TkDodo You're right. I'm not fully aware about the question.

Answer (score 6):

You can also call `setCity` in the `onSubmit` event of the form, as the `onSubmit` event gets the complete submitted form in the submit event:

```
<form
  onSubmit={(event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const city = new FormData(event.currentTarget).get("city");
    // do validation here
    if (isValid(city)) {
      setCity(city)
    }
>
  <input name="city" type="text" />
  <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

make sure to give your input a `name` so that you can grab it from the form submit event.